# Adjusting the size of hover's highlight box with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to change the size of hover's highlight box in <li'> when i clicked it using CSS? this is for my navigation bar.

I want to change the size of the active highlight box's size if possible.

```
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#new">New Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="#search">Search Order</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Post your css as well please.

Comment: @Ayied Farith can you please elaborate on what you are about to say, and also mention what you have tried. That will be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: sorry about that, I've already edit the post. In summary i want to adjust the highlight's box size when clicking with mouse if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line of code into the css to change the size of the anchor element on click.

```
li a:focus {
    transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

if you're trying to change the size on hover it would be:

```
li a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.08);
}
```